# How can I set the container div's width for a mobile site with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, responsive

I'm making a mobile only website like "m.domainname.com".
I want to use Bootstrap in my site. But, for the main container div, if I use the "container" class, it will be 1170px. My site starts with 1024px.

How can I set the container div's width? Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

How about change the container width from 1170 to 1024px?. Have a look into bootstrap.css and change this

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

to

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1024px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site is only for mobile then you don't need to use the `@media (min-width:1200)` for your css. You can just do something like this if you don't want to set an actual amount:

```
.container {width:95%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's `container-fluid` class if you don't need to set an explicit width for the container. From their [Grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

If you do need to set explicit widths for the container at different breakpoints, you can [generate a customized CSS file for Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) using your numbers. The link allows you to set a container width for:

- tablet
- small
- desktop
- medium
- large desktop
- large

It also allows you to change a lot of the other defaults.